# document.write appends null in ChromeOs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-os, document.write

I parse two values to my print.html file like this: .../print.html?name=Peter%20Gram&city=Torshavn. In the file I receive them like this:

```
<script>
const name = urlParams.get('name')
const city = urlParams.get('city')
```

and output it like this:

```
...
<tr><td>Name:<br><script>document.write(name)</script>
<tr><td>City:<br><script>document.write(city)</script>
...
```

Doing so I get

*Name:*
*Peter Gramnull*

*City:*
*Torshavn*

Why does ChromeOS append the "null"? It only occurs on Chromebook, not on my windows PC (Chrome browser). In my real life situation I pass 5 parms. Three of them have a space in them (%20) and  all of those three come out with the "null" appended.

Comment: Is this inline? Why not use innerText instead. It is really not recommended to use document.write and if you do it after the page has loaded the page is wiped

Comment: Show urlParams please

Comment: I may add, that the print.html resides on the local Chromebook (127.0.0.1:8887) in order to permit the use of the camera to add a photo to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show urlParams please.

I suggest this:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when page has loaded
  const url = new URL(`https://example.com/print.html?name=Peter%20Gram&city=Torshavn`)
  const name = url.searchParams.get("name");
  const city = url.searchParams.get("city");
  document.getElementById("name").textContent = name;
  document.getElementById("city").textContent = city;

  // using queryString:

  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(`?name=Peter%20Gram&city=Torshavn`);
  const n = urlParams.get('name')
  document.getElementById("b").textContent = n;
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:<br/><span id="name"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City:<br/><span id="city"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Still works:<br/><span id="b"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Good idea. I'll try that and come back tomorrow or so with the result.

Comment: I cannot make it work. here is a snippet of my code:
`
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const a = urlParams.get('a')

Comment: I cannot make it work. here is a snippet of my code:
`
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const name = urlParams.get('a')
console.log(name)
document.getElementById("b").textContent = name
`
I get this: _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent') at ..."_ although console.log shows that name is not null

Comment: Yes: <span id="b"></span>

The browser debugger points to: " = name"

Comment: Your demo worked for me when I reversed the order: HTML code first. Script afterwards.

Comment: DUH! or wrap in `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { /* your code here */ });`